# function flash is not working reder_404 Redmine 1.3 Ruby ruby 1.8.7 Rails 2.3.14

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I'm trying to show this error message, but it does not appear when render 404 Redmine page. What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advanced!

This is my code:

```
def file_readable

    if @attachment.readable?
         true
    else
        flash.now[:error] = "This file has been removed"
        render_404
    end
  end
```

Ruby ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358)

Rails 2.3.14

```
** LOCAL GEMS **

actionmailer (2.3.14)
actionpack (2.3.14)
activerecord (2.3.14)
activeresource (2.3.14)
activesupport (2.3.14)
color (1.4.1)
daemon_controller (1.0.0)
fastthread (1.0.7)
i18n (0.4.2)
icalendar (1.2.1)
json (1.7.5)
mime-types (1.19)
mysql (2.8.1)
passenger (3.0.13)
pdf-writer (1.1.8)
rack (1.1.3)
rails (2.3.14)
rake (10.1.1, 0.8.7)
rdoc (3.12)
transaction-simple (1.4.0.2)
```

Comment: what is the methods `#render_404`?

Comment: Render 404 error page

Comment: verify, weither the error text is present on the generated page? then try to render non-404-error page, and provide results.

Comment: If you just want to show a 404 page then you can just render via the path of the 404 page

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

My previous answer was wrong because i misunderstood the question.

Take a look at [this code](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/edavis10/redmine/ApplicationController%3arender_404).

I think the correct way of displaying custom message is following:

```
render_404 :message => "This file has been removed"
```

Comment: I think the error is on the ruby gems or ruby and rails version